# making a memory only fileobject in python with pyfilesystem

Tags: python, memory, filesystems

I have written a motion detection/ video program using opencv2 which saves video output for x seconds.   if motion in detected during that time, the output is saved as an alternate named file, but if not motion is detected then the file is overwritten.  To avoid needless wear on a flash based memory system, I want to write the file to the RAM, and if motion is detected then save it to the non-volatile memory.

I am trying to create this file in the RAM using pyfilesystem-fs.memoryfs

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time, os, threading, thread
from Tkinter import *
from fs.memoryfs import MemoryFS

class stuff:

    mem=MemoryFS()
    output = mem.createfile('output.avi')
    rectime=0
    delay=0
    kill=0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\motion\\output.avi',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('F','M','P','4'), 30, (640,480),True)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('F','M','P','4'), 30, (640,480),True)
```

This is the motion detection part

```
if value > 100:
        print "saving"
        movement=time.time()
        while time.time()<int(movement)+stuff.rectime:
            stuff.out.write(frame)
            ret, frame = stuff.cap.read()


        if stuff.out.isOpened() is True:
            stuff.out.release()
        os.rename(stuff.output, 'c:\motion\\' + time.strftime('%m-%d-%y_%H-%M-%S') + '.avi')
```

the os.rename function returns `TypeError must be string, not None`

I'm clearly using memoryfs incorrectly, but cannot find any examples of its use.

EDIT
I use the following line to open the file object and write to it

```
stuff.out.open(stuff.output, cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'FMP4'),24,(640,480),True)
```

however this returns `False` , I'm not sure but it appears it can't open the file object.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `io.BytesIO` or `cStringIO`?

Comment: probably because I ran into memoryFS first.  Could you give me an example of how to implement this to save the video to the buffer then write the buffer to a file.

Comment: Em. Maybe, it isn't clear to you that mem.createfile(...) returns None. Always. Not a file object.

Comment: @shhdup I thought of that after I looked at it again.  I then did `f = mem.open('output.avi')` but this is an _io.TextWrapperIO type, not a string or unicode type.

Comment: Yes, it's file-like object. You could read from it with `f.read()`

Comment: @shhdup I think my problem is that opencv2 videowriter does not want to use the buffer as a file to write to.  the VideoWriter.open function wants a string or unicode type and I"m not sure how to make my buffer be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To move your file form MemoryFS to real file system, you should read orig file and write it to dest file, something like

```
with mem.open('output.avi', 'b') as orig:
    with open('c:\\motion\\' + time.strftime('%m-%d-%y_%H-%M-%S') + '.avi')) as dest:
        dest.write(orig.read())
```

Comment: Use `shutil.copyfileobj()` or else you run out of RAM.

Comment: And don't forget to limit chunks size, or you run out of RAM whatever ;)

Comment: I think the problem comes before that point.  it is calling my `output` a `None` object.