# Python: named in-memory file with actual disk-file semantics?

Tags: python, file, memory, buffer

I know I can use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` to return an open file handle that can be written to and read from.

However, I'm looking for a way to make an in-memory region look like a named disk file that has not yet been opened.

The reason I want this is because there are routines which take the name of a disk file as an argument, and these routines then open the file and manipulate it. In some cases, I want the input or output for these routines to be a memory buffer, not a disk file, and for those routines, I can't pass an already-open file handle.

For example, one such routine is `Image.save()` from `PIL`, which expects a path name as its argument, not an already open file handle. When using that routine, I'd like the image data to be saved directly to a memory buffer, without any intermediate file IO being performed. There are also many other routines that take path names as arguments for which I would like this same behavior.

Is there any way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: `Image.save()` will happily take a file pointer in place of a filename, so you can use `BytesIO` with it.

Comment: Hmm ... that failed when I tried it, but I'll try again. Perhaps I was making some other error. However, I still am looking for a general solution to this problem. I only used `Image.save()` as an example.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. You could conceivably do what you want by overriding `open` and returning a `BytesIO` object for special paths (however you define "special") rather than a file.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see. Yes, I am thinking of something like that. I was just hoping that some package might already exist which does what i want. But if not, I'll write one. With regard specifically to `Image.save()`, it turns out that I have to previously set the name of the BytesIO buffer via something like `byteiobuffer.name = "foo.jpg"`, because `Image.save()` looks at that `name` attribute in order to get the image type.

Comment: Check this out, it might be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321216/making-a-memory-only-fileobject-in-python-with-pyfilesystem

Comment: Yes, that memory file system looks like it might indeed be what I'm looking for. Thank you. I'll investigate more, and if it turns out to do what I think it does, I'll post a reference to this as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the suggestion by Shmulik Asafi, I can use the memory file system within `pyfilesystem`: [making a memory only fileobject in python with pyfilesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321216/making-a-memory-only-fileobject-in-python-with-pyfilesystem)

Also see http://pyfilesystem.org/

I have tested this, and it indeed seems to give me what I want.

Comment: It would be useful if you added an example of how to create a file in memory and access it by name using pyfilesystem.