# How to feed a python buffer-/file- object to a library that expects a filename without writing the buffer to disk?

Tags: python, file, buffer, temporary-files, in-memory

Here is an example that is pretty close to my actual usecase:

```
import skvideo.io
from smart_open import smart_open

with smart_open("s3://{}/{}".format("my_bucket", resource_key)) as f:
    magic = NamedInMemoryTempFile(f, "video.vp8")  # is there sth like that?
    print(magic)  # probably sth. like "/python/fakepath/video.vp8"
    frames = skvideo.io.vread(magic)  # some lib that expects a filename :/ ...
    do_something_with(frames)
```

- I use smart_open to directly read a file from AWS S3 into memory
- I would like to use skvideo to decode the video file into a 4-dimensional numpy array. But skvideo does not expose an interface to pass a video directly as a buffer, but only as a filename

So I'm searching for a way to keep stuff in memory and avoid writing to disk for performance reasons.

Comment: Perhaps this documentation might be useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io%20buffer#buffered-streams and https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: You could edit the source of skvideo.io and replace the function that loads from the file to the buffer.

Comment: Thanks you two :)
@Idlehands As I said, I have already a buffer. Problem is that it doesn't have a filename. Regarding tempfiles: As far as I understand, what I need is a SpooledTemporaryFile that is also a NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: @TomAtix, It's just that I was facing this kind of issue a few times already and was hoping there might be sth. out there... But I'll go for your suggestion if this hypothetical thing I'm searching for does not exist.

Comment: I believe in this case it's hard to avoid having a TempFile since `skvideo.io` is specifically looking for a file path, which AFAIK cannot be directed to an in-memory object.  One possible but very tedious workaround would be to temporarily overwrite the function responsible for parsing the `fname` in the module to use a stream buffer instead... but as far as I can see in the source code, it goes pretty deep.  So `SpooledTemporaryFile` would be your best bet IMO, and would avoid writing to disk if you don't exceed the `max_size`.

Comment: Did you check pyfilesystem? This might be exactly what you are looking for, although I have never used it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321216/making-a-memory-only-fileobject-in-python-with-pyfilesystem

Comment: @TomAtix Cool stuff! I will keep it in mind. But I think its not a solution to my problem, because whats missing is a path that can get resolved by pythons own `open` function (afaics). Most likely this is not even possible from within python

Comment: I think pyfilesystem can do this: `mem = MemoryFS()` and then `mem.createfile('anyname.anytype')` and then you can open it like any other file `with open('anyname.anytype') as thefile:` !

Comment: I tried, it cant. :/
It can be opened by `fs.opener.open('mem://anyname.anytype')`, but the vanilla python `open` doesn't understand this and just throws an `IOError`. Same for `open('anyfile.anytype')` (which makes sense, because it would be ambiguous in case there is really such a file)